# VBA—"Error 1004: Unable to get the CurrentPage property of the PivotField class"

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook containing multiple worksheets with multiple pivot tables on each worksheet. I'm attempting to loop through every pivot table and change its 'Report Function' filter to a user-specified value selected from a List Box. All the pivot tables have the "Report Function" filter.

I have around 50 pivot tables, and the code successfully changes the filters for all but around 8 pivots. Those 8 pivot tables' filters don't change; instead, the error "Error 1004: Unable to get the CurrentPage property of the PivotField class" is returned.

wHY is this code returning this error for a small number of pivot tables?

Strangely, it seems to be the exact same pivot tables that are returning this error.

```
Sub ChangePivotFilter(str As String)

Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim aWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim myPivot As Excel.PivotTable
Dim myPivotField As Excel.PivotField

Set aWB = ActiveWorkbook
For Each ws In aWB.Worksheets

    For Each myPivot In ws.PivotTables
        Set myPivotField = Nothing

        On Error Resume Next
        Set myPivotField = myPivot.PivotFields("Report Function")
        myPivotField.CurrentPage = str
    Next myPivot
Next ws

End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: are you sure there are any results matching for `str` for "Report Function" `PivotField` ? In all tables ?

Comment: Are you getting that error even though you have On Error Resume Next?

Comment: @Shai Rado Yes, there is a match for str in the Report Function field of all pivot tables.

Comment: @Sam I'm not, no. I previously placed an error check line in the code that returned the error. With 'On Error Resume Next' the code doesn't display the error.

Answer (score 2):

Assigning to, or reading from `CurrentPage` will fail if the PivotField isn't physically in "page" (i.e. a "Filter") on its PivotTable:

[image: PivotField in page]

You can programmatically send a PivotField to "page" by setting its Orientation property to xlPageField, as follows:

```
myPivotField.Orientation = xlPageField
```