# excel - filter pivot table based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a function that filters a pivot table based on a cell value. the target cell is on C2 in Sheet1. the pivot table is in the same sheet. any idea why this sub doesn't work?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xPTable As PivotTable
    Dim xPFile As PivotField
    Dim xStr As String
    On Error Resume Next
    If Intersect(Target, Range("C2:C3")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xPTable = Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable2")
    Set xPFile = xPTable.PivotFields("category")
    xStr = Target.Text
    xPFile.ClearAllFilters
    xPFile.CurrentPage = xStr
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Comment out the `On Error Resume Next` and see what happens

Comment: @TimWilliams unable to set currentpage property of the pivotfield class

Comment: There's the problem then....  Maybe check here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45203856/vba-error-1004-unable-to-get-the-currentpage-property-of-the-pivotfield-class